# porting kde application to windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, sdk, kde-plasma

hy

I'm trying to port a KDE application to windows

my problem is finding a suitable KDE SDK for windows, i can't include any k-headers (kapplication.h kaction.h ....) and I haven't even got to the libs

is there a guide for doing things like this

Answer (score 1):

KDE 4 is intended to natively support windows so it should be less of a "porting" effort and more of a "getting it to compile as-is" effort (though there will likely be a few minor changes). You should be able to find the relevant information on the [KDE on Windows site](http://techbase.kde.org/Projects/KDE_on_Windows). Specifically, there is a [porting](http://techbase.kde.org/Projects/KDE_on_Windows/Porting_Guidelines) section in their wiki for ensuring KDE apps run under windows.

Comment: I installed KDE on windows but I don't see any headers and libraries, only dlls.

also from what I saw the porting sections contains only information about writing platform-independent code

Comment: I think you need to install KDE in 'Package Manager Mode' in order to be able to install header files since your average user won't want them. The following link describes how to set up your build environment: http://techbase.kde.org/Getting_Started/Build/KDE4/Windows/DistributionBasedBuild